# Place Chrome Extension icon in Notification Area (Windows)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notification-area

I am developing an extension for the Chrome browser with the API provided. I was just wondering if it is possible to place an app/extension (icon) in the notification area for easy access like the *Google Hangouts* app.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API for that. Hangouts is either using a private API or a [native host module](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to achieve this.

Existing feature requests:

Extensions: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72068 (in limbo)
Apps: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142450 (<strike>seems implemented but not promoted to stable</strike> **WontFix**)

**EDIT:** The App API feature request is closed as WontFix. This is unlikely to be implemented.